# Accessing private struct of a class using auto

Tags: c++, c++11

I discovered that next weird code compiles and runs (on VS 2019):

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    private:
    struct Priv
    {
        int a;
    };
    
    public:
    static Priv WeirdFunc() {return {42};}; 
};

int main()
{
    auto val = Test::WeirdFunc();
    std::cout << val.a;
}
```

Output is 42, no problems here.

The issue I see is that auto keyword allows us to access private structure "Priv".
If I try to replace auto with Test::Priv I get compile error, as expected.
From the articles on the internet I found out that you can have to use auto for lambdas, but this case was never mentioned.

Also, if I try to output "Test::WeirdFunc().a" it also works

So my questions are:

- Is it expected behaviour for auto to let us access private structures/classes?
- Is it allowed to declare public function that returns private structure?
- Is it expected behaviour that we can access private structures/classes if it's return value of function (e.g. "Test::WeirdFunc().a")?

All of that is obviously terrible code style, but I'm curious about whether it's valid c++ code or not

Comment: Unfortunately this is a valid C++ code.

Comment: There is a similar trick with returning pointers to private embedded classes (I once learned in A. Alexandrescus Modern C++ Design): [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92c7da95fefae911) The goal is to provide a boolean result without explicit having a `bool` conversion operator (which would provide unintended other incompatibilities).

Comment: A lesson to learn is that `public`/`private` only affects *names*. For example, you can't access private members of a class by asking for the field by name, but you can if you are granted a pointer-to-data-member to it since that doesn't require knowing or using the name of the field. The same concept applies here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `Test::WeirdFunc()` is a `Priv`. This is also the auto-deducted type of `val`. The `auto` keyword removes the necessity to *name* the type of `val` to be `Priv` and therefore, the compiler does not complain. As a result, `val` is of (unmentioned) type `Priv` and has a *public* member `a`, that can be accessed freely.

So the answers to all your questions is: *Yes*, (as long as you don't "mention" the name of the nested class).

See also: [cpp reference on nested classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions are:
>
> - Is it expected behaviour for auto to let us access private structures/classes?

Yes.

> - Is it allowed to declare public function that returns private structure?

Yes.

> - Is it expected behaviour that we can access private structures/classes if it's return value of function (e.g. `Test::WeirdFunc().a`)?

Yes.

> All of that is obviously terrible code style, ...

No, not necessarily. Think about e.g. a container class, which defines iterator classes as internal nested types:

```
class Container {
     class iterator {
     public:
          iterator operator++(); 
          iterator operator++(int); 
     };

public:
     iterator begin();
     iterator end();
};
```

This allows to access the `iterator`'s instances and operations via `auto`, but not to directly create instances from outside the class.

Answer (score 2):

You have a *public interface* which *exposes a type* by means of the type of return value of the public interface. This essentially means your API design exposes private details of the class, and this is not an issue of the C++ language features but of the API design. Note that this doesn't just apply for `auto`:

```
using A = decltype(Test::WeirdFunc());  // A is Test::Priv.
A a{};  // well-formed.
```

Comment: Unbelievable but true. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/699688c2bb4fc3a8)

Answer (score 0):

It's valid, and here's why:

**Access specifiers control access to *names*.**

So, you have no access to the *name* `Priv`, but that doesn't mean you have no access to the type it's referring to. And there are other ways to "get to it", such as by using `auto`.

This is not as crazy as you might think. After all, you can't do any damage with it: if you don't want public things returning instances of "private types" (which aren't, really, but that's fine) then simply don't do that thing.